Seed symbol in Slavic folklore
I came upon this symbol and was curious if it has a specific name (like "kolovrat") and what its symbolism is in Slavic folklore.


This eight-pointed star/flower is called ruzha or rozha, which means "mallow" in Ukrainian, and is a common decorative motif on Ukrainian pysanky (decorated Easter eggs). Various interpretations for the meaning of this symbol exist in the literature.
For example, this is what Mykhailo Selivachov has to say about the ruzha in his book Folk Designs of Ukraine (p. 16):

Mallow (rozha) is usually a flower with eight petals, without any express botanical features [...]

and (p. 47):

In Ukrainian ornaments a star of eight rhombic elements is also called a "mallow" and a single girl is also often associated with this flower. A girl's beauty is compared to a bright star or a full mallow, whereas in the naming of the design both names refer to the same sign - a star made of eight rhombic elements.

At page 20 in The Ukranian Folk Pysanka by Vira Manko, instead, it is stated that the ruzha  probably originated as a pre-Christian solar symbol, and therefore might (emphasis on "might") be associated with the Slavic god Dazhbog. Similar claims are made here and here.
For more examples, variations, and details on this motif, I recommend visiting this page.

interestingly, "ruzha" in south slavic languages means rose
